# jQuery: Button clicked, but no action. AngularJS?

Tags: jquery

I am having problems. This is my code:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" ng-click="test.setGridView('today')" ng-class="{active: test.gridView === 'today'}"><i class="fa fa-bar-graphics"></i>Today</a>
```

This is I am trying to click it (The path I got from `Copy CSS Path`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#... div > a:nth-child(1)").click( function(){
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

But there's no action. The website is built using AngularJS.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what selector is this `#...` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, this I shortened the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to trigger a click event, use `$('yourSelector').trigger('click');`  This will execute the function in the `ng-click` attribute.

Comment: nope, I don't need the function to fire. I just need the reaction when I click 'a'

Comment: Try deleting the ng-click handler